# Hartshorne exercise II.6.3(a)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have difficulties on Hartshorne Exercise II.6.3. Part(a) is: $\mathbb{V}$ is a projective variety of dimension $\geq 1$ and nonsingular in codimension 1. Let $X$ be the affine cone over $V$ in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$, and $\bar{X}$ be the projective closure. Then we can cover $V$ with open sets $U_i$ so that under the projection $\pi:\ \bar{X}-\{P\} \rightarrow V$, we have $(\pi)^{-1}(U_i) \cong U_i \times_k \mathbb{A}^1$. After that, we can show $(\pi)^*:\ Cl(V) \tilde{\rightarrow} Cl(\bar{X}-P)$ is an iso.

I have already proved such $U_i$ exists and I don't know how to continue since I don't know how to use these $U_i$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is the result saying that $Cl(U_i \times \mathbb{A}^1_k) \cong Cl(Y)$ and the $U_i$ is a cover of $V$.

Comment: @hm2020 I'm sorry but I wonder how to prove the result or which book can I refer to?

Comment: "locally" you have isomorphisms $Cl(U_i \times \mathbb{A}^1) \cong Cl(U_i)$. Is it possible to "glue these isomorphisms" in some way to get a globally defined map?

Comment: The Picard group $Pic(X):=H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X^*)$ has a "sheaf theoretic" definition. Similar for the group of Cartier divisors $CaCl(X):=H^0(X, K_X^*/\mathcal{O}_X^*)$.

Comment: @hm2020 that's not appropriate for this exercise - it's a problem about class groups, not Cartier divisors or Picard groups, and sheaf cohomology has not been introduced yet in the book.

Comment: @tensor - Prop II.6.25 in the same chapter proves that $CaCl(X) \cong Pic(X)$ is an isomorphism when $X$ is integral, hence you may interpret elements $L \in Pic(X)$ as global sections of the sheaf of abelian groups $K_X^*/\mathcal{O}_X^*$.

Comment: @tensor - If $Z:=\overline{X}-P$, there is a canonical map $\pi^*:Pic(V) \rightarrow H^0(Z, K_Z^*/\mathcal{O}_Z^*)$ of abelian groups. It may be you can use the cover $U_i$ of $V$ and the fact you have interpreted elements in the Picard group as global sections of a sheaf of abelian groups to conclude. This would give an alternative approach where you learn how to work with Cartier divisors.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Cl}{Cl}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}$

Indeed, one can "glue" the isomorphism $\Cl(U_i)\simeq\Cl(\pi^{-1}U_i)$ in some sense.

It's easy to prove the following lemma: (Just unwind the defintions)

> Lemma: Let $X$ be a noetherian, integral, separated scheme which is regular in codim 1. Let $Z_i$ be prime divisor of $X$, s.t. $\{U_i=X-Z_i\}_i$ forms an open cover of $X$. Let $D$ a divisor on $X$.
> Suppose that $D|_{U_i}=\Div_{U_i}(f)$ is the principal divisor on $U_i$ determined by a common $f$. Then $D=\Div_X(f)$ is the principal divisor on $X$ determined by the same $f$.

We can use this lemma to show the well-defineness and injectivity of $\pi^*:\Cl(V)\to\Cl(\bar{X}-P)$.

> Well-defined:
> Let $D=\Div_V(f)$ be a principal divisor on $V$, then $D|_{U_i}=\Div_{U_i}(f)$. By Hartshorne II Prop 6.6. $(\pi^*D)|_{\pi^{-1}\ U_i}=\pi^*(D|_{U_i})=\Div_{\pi^{-1}\ U_i}(f)$. Thus $\pi^*D=\Div_{\bar{X}-P}(f)$ by Lemma.

> Injectivity:
> Assume that $\pi^*D=\Div_{\bar{X}-P}(f)$, $f\in K(\bar{X}-P)$
> Then $\pi^*(D|_{U_i})=\Div_{\pi^{-1}\ U_i}(f)$. By Hart II 6.6. $f\in K(U_i)=K(V)$, $D|_{U_i}=\Div_{U_i}(f)$.
> By Lemma again, $D=\Div_V(f)$.

The surjectivity is fairly easy to prove. For example, use Four Lemma and the localization sequence:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z} @>{Z_i}>> \Cl(V) @>>> \Cl(U_i) @>>> 0 \\
@VV{=}V @VV{\pi^*}V @V{\simeq}V{\pi^*}V\\
\mathbb{Z} @>{\pi^*Z_i}>> \Cl(\bar{X}-P) @>>> \Cl(\pi^{-1}U_i) @>>> 0
\end{CD}

Comment: Why can you choose such a cover? I understand if $V=\mathbb{P}^n$ but not in general?

Comment: @Elad This proof doesn't require the cover being finite. You may just take all prime divisors of $X$. (And for many examples we can take a finite subcover, I think.)

Comment: But in this problem, we are using a cover with certain properties. The cover should be of the kind $(\pi)^{-1}\left(U_i\right) \cong U_i \times_k \mathbb{A}^1$ for the right down arrow to be an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have that the $U_i$ exist with the desired property, you can use the logic of proposition II.6.6:

> **Proposition II.6.6.** Let $X$ be a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimension one. Then $X\times\Bbb A^1$ ($=X\times_{\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z} \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z[t]$) is also a noetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimension one, and $\operatorname{Cl} X\cong \operatorname{Cl}(X\times\Bbb A^1)$.

The way this proof runs is that there are two types of codimension one points in $X\times\Bbb A^1$: those that have image a codimension-one point in $X$ under the natural projection, and those that map to the generic point of $X$ under the natural projection. One can define a map $\operatorname{Cl} X \to \operatorname{Cl} (X\times\Bbb A^1)$ by sending $\sum n_i[Y_i] \mapsto \sum n_i[\pi^{-1}(Y_i)]$, then check that it's injective by considering points of the first type. To show surjectivity, it's enough to show that the closures of points of the second type are all linearly equivalent to closures of points of the first type, and one does this by noting that $K(X)[t]$, the coordinate algebra of the fiber over the generic point of $X$, is a PID. So for any closed point in this fiber (aka point of the second type), we can find a function in $K(X)[t]$ which vanishes there and nowhere else on the fiber over the generic point. This proves surjectivity.

You can basically copy this proof verbatim for exercise II.6.3(a). The fact that $\overline{X}\setminus P\to V$ is locally like $U_i\times\Bbb A^1\to U_i$ gives you all the structure to make the proof work correctly: one can define a map in the same way and then check injectivity and surjectivity in the same way.